# How can I store in a view a reference to another view?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make "Information" textviews with expandable content. The user sees a textview displaying "Information", and on click/tap, another textview (was hidden until now) appears containing the information.

Here's the XML:

```
<!-- Information expandable block-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/element_background"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/home_screen_elements_spacing">
            <!-- Information block title -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/app_schedule_fri_information"
                android:tag="app_schedule_fri_information_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                style="@style/AppTheme"
                android:text="@string/app_home_information"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextBody"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:onClick="toggle_contents"/>
            <!-- Information block content to hide/show -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/app_schedule_fri_information_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                style="@style/AppTheme"
                android:text="@string/app_home_information_text"
                android:textColor="@color/colorTextBody"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Here's the "toggle_content" function called on click:

```
public void toggle_contents(View v){
    TextView content = <GET_REF_TO_CONTENT>;
    content.setVisibility( content.isShown()
            ? View.GONE
            : View.VISIBLE );
}
```

**What I need:**

As you can see, I'm stuck. I'm looking for a way to store a reference to the content Textview within the title Textview. Upon being called, toggle_content() will recover that reference from the title view (such as v.getTag() ) and use it to locate the content and toggle it.

**What I tried:**

I tried to store the id of the content textview in a tag on the title textview (actually present in the above xml), but failed to convert the tag to an id.

Comment: You should handle this stuff in their common parent, which will always know its children. You can use styleable -+ compound viewgroup to solve your problem. https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view#applyattr

Answer (score 0):

That's not sexy but it works:

```
public void toggle_contents(View v){
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(v.getTag().toString(), "id", this.getPackageName());
    TextView content = findViewById(id);
    content.setVisibility( content.isShown()
            ? View.GONE
            : View.VISIBLE );
}
```

Hoping someone can provide a better answer, because this looks like the kind of hack a future update would break.

Answer (score 0):

Use a click listener on the first textview and a toggle to make the second one appear/disappear with every other click, by setting its visibility to VISIBLE/GONE:

```
TextView information = (TextView) findViewById(R.idapp_schedule_fri_information);
TextView informationText = (TextView) findViewById(app_schedule_fri_information_text);

information.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (informationText.isVisible()) {
                   informationText.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
                } else {
                   informationText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the id. 
If you already stored the reference of the `informationText` in `information`'s tag, like:

```
information.setTag(informationText);
```

then you can retrieve it like this:

```
public void toggle_contents(View v){
    TextView content = ((TextView) v).getTag();
    content.setVisibility( content.isShown()
            ? View.GONE
            : View.VISIBLE );
}
```

So instead of storing in the `tag` the name of the `TextView` you can store a reference to the `TextView` itself and not bother with finding its id.